# issue with calculating percentage in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

This is my query. which each query (counter,denominator) works good alone. when I'm trying to devide these 2 queries I'm getting this
 **ERROR: syntax error at or near "/"**
I'm trying to get % of total price in the first 3 months of 2016 (SPORT & MUSIC) from total price of all 2016 in the same departments

```
(SELECT "Total Price"
FROM "Sales"
WHERE "Department" IN('SPORT','MUSIC')
AND "DATE" BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-03-31')/(SELECT "Total Price"
FROM "Sales"
WHERE "Department" IN('SPORT','MUSIC')
AND "DATE" BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31') AS percentage
```

Comment: That query makes no sense to me. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: You are selecting the data for three months and there might be many records in that period. Do you want the sum of all the "total price" in first 3 months of 2016 (SPORT & MUSIC) from total price of all 2016 in the same departments? can you please be more specific about what you are seeking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean something like

```
SELECT
   "Total Price"/(sum("Total Price") OVER ()) * 100.0 AS percentage
FROM "Sales"
WHERE "Department" IN ('SPORT','MUSIC')
  AND "DATE" BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-03-31';
```

Do yourself a favour and avoid names with upper or mixed case and non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: One more thing. How can i calculate % of total sales from all sales within the years?

Comment: I tried this one, but getting an error: SELECT "Total Price"
FROM "Sales"
WHERE "Department" IN('SPORT','MUSIC')
/(SELECT SUM("Total Price")
FROM "Sales") * 100.0 AS percentage

Comment: That's not SQL... Anyway, you should start a new question for that and carefully explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'll try to explain myself again.Hoppefully, better.  I would like to calculate % of total price of MUSIC as a part of all departments per the table below

Comment: S_Id DATE Year Branch ID Department Num_Of Products Total Price Branch_City Employee_Id
111 1/12/2014 2014 1 SPORT 2 100 Tel Aviv 22
112 2/1/2015 2015 2 TOYS 10 155 Herzelia 1
113 4/16/2013 2013 3 MUSIC 1 255 Haifa 999
22200 1/22/2016 2016 4 HOME 5 3000 Hod Hasharon 78
12 11/13/2016 2016 5 CLOTHING 12 400 Natania 88
3333 1/5/2016 2016 6 ELECTRONICS 3 25000 Tel Aviv 22
444 1/30/2016 2016 7 MUSIC 2 600 Yahud 344
8888 1/30/2016 2016 8 CLOTHING 10 1000 Yahud 333

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT sum("Total Price") FILTER (WHERE "Department" IN ('SPORT', 'MUSIC')) OVER () / sum("Total Price") OVER () * 100.0 AS percentage FROM "Sales";`